# Run a Modal after X amount of time

Tags: javascript, php, modal-dialog

I'm running Reveal Modal and its working fine with a link like this below.

```
<a href="#" data-reveal-id="myModal" data-animation="none">
        None
</a>
```

But i have been trying to get this code to run after x amount of time with setTimeout() function with no luck. Can anyone help?

Comment: You should post your code.

Comment: im using http://zurb.com/playground/reveal-modal-plugin... stackoverflow wont let me post that much code :/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#myModal').reveal();
    }, 1000);
}
```

Or this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#myModal').foundation('reveal', 'open');
});
```

Source: [reveal](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/reveal.html)

This will reveal the modal 1 second after the page loads

Comment: Still nothing, i tried something like this with no luck. I think that the modal plugin (Reveal) im using has extra parameters like 'data-reveal-id'

Comment: Just added another way to open the modal and where I founded.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the docs, i didnt see them, will have a look now, still not getting it to fire though

Comment: It's not the best way, but you can try trigger the **click** event of the link. `$(function() { $('a[data-reveal-id]').click() });`